# Installing Ubuntu 14 on an acer timeline x

Tags: windows, acer

Managed to get the DVD to run
Got as far as install inside windows7
System then asks me to remove dvd then the system reboots and returns to windows
I have created a partion on the HD I made it primary not logical does this affect the process. help please

Answer (score 0):

To install ubuntu simply:

1. Insert the disk into your computer.
2. Restart your computer.
3. Press f9 (Or the key that says boot menu on the screen)
4. When ubuntu loads select install from the list.
5. Work through the guide.
6. When you get to the partition stage select the partition you made
7. Your done!

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: @Steve boot ubuntu live cd and run from terminal sudo update-grub.this will add the boot entry of ubuntu in grub.